# ToExpression[ToString[x^2]] does not produce x^2

Tags: string-manipulation

`ToExpression[ToString[x^2]]` does not produce $x^2$, instead it gives $x$. Please explain.

I actually wrote the following code and it gave the answer as 1.

```
C1 = (Subscript[x, 1][t] - Subscript[x, 0])^2 + (Subscript[y, 1][t] - 
     Subscript[y, 0])^2 - Subscript[l, 01]^2;
ToExpression[StringDelete[ToString[C1], "[t]"]]
```

Then I tried with $x^2$ to get $x$ only.

Comment: Always look at intermediate results. Look at what ToString produces and it will be clear what happens. It uses OutuptForm by default, which is meant for producing human-readable expressions in a terminal. If you use InputForm, then it can be convert back to an expression.  However, I have to say that trying to manipulate expressions as strings is a _very very bad idea_.

Comment: fyi: `C1 /. h_[t] :> h`

Answer (score 3):

`ToExpression[ToString[x^2, InputForm]]` returns the expression that you requested.

It seems that the InputForm parameter in ToString is needed to subsequently use ToExpression.

Comment: Was late with respect to @Szabolcs that gave the more precise answer/comment.